# slider does not display in home page

Tags: magento2, banner-slider

after installing sparsh banner extention and adding {{ block class="Sparsh\Banner\Block\Banner" template="Sparsh_Banner::banner.phtml" }} this code in home page but in forntend home page display error Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined index: directiveName in C:\wamp64\www\sejal\vendor\magento\framework\Filter\DirectiveProcessor\SimpleDirective.php on line 68
how to resolve it??? plese help me to get out of this error

Comment: Make sure Your banners is enable

Comment: First, need to remove whitespace before the block.